# How to optimize array grouping?

Tags: javascript

I have an array that is constantly updated and accordingly it is necessary to update its grouping. Example of an array:

```
[
 {
    "price": 2419.62,
    "amount": 0.0266
  },
  {
    "price": 1927.52,
    "amount": 0.0217
  },
  ...
]
```

I tried different options. At the moment this option is the fastest:

```
      const points = [
           {
              "price": 2419.62,
              "amount": 0.0266
            },
            {
              "price": 1927.52,
              "amount": 0.0217
            },
            ...
          ];
      const range = 500;
      const spread = 1800;
      const countGroup = 250;
      const sizeUnitGroup = range / countGroup;
      const groups = {};
      for (let i = 0;  i < countGroup; i++){
        groups[i] = [];
        try {
          points.forEach((item, id) => {
            if (item.price > spread + (i*sizeUnitGroup) && item.price <= spread + (i*sizeUnitGroup + sizeUnitGroup)){
              groups[i].push(item);
              points.splice(id, 1);
            }
            if (item.price > (spread + (i*sizeUnitGroup + sizeUnitGroup))) throw BreakException;
          });
        } catch (e) {
        }
      }
```

But even so, this function works for too long. Any ideas how this can be optimized?

Comment: What is the logic of the grouping?

Comment: Please post an example update for your example array (how are things regrouped?).

Comment: That's a lot of iterating and splicing. Wouldn't it be better to just iterate the `points` array and figure out which group each one should go into?

Comment: @doodlemeister You mean this is it? https://pastebin.com/C7kh6ba6

Comment: Yes, did that help? It avoids the `.splice()`, which has to reindex the array every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could calculate the interval for pushing the value to the wanted slot.

```js
var points = [
        { price: 2419.62, amount: 0.0266 },
        { price: 1927.52, amount: 0.0217 },
        { price: 1800, amount: 0.07 },              // -1 not in result
        { price: 1800.000000000001, amount: 0.07 }, //  0
        { price: 1802, amount: 0.07 },              //  0
    ],
    range = 500,
    spread = 1800,
    countGroup = 250,
    sizeUnitGroup = range / countGroup,
    groups = {};

points.forEach((item, id) => {
    var i = Math.ceil((item.price - spread- sizeUnitGroup) / sizeUnitGroup);
    if (i >= 0 && i < countGroup) {
        groups[i] = groups[i] || [];
        groups[i].push(item);
    }
});

console.log(groups);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```